# Too big UI of few programs, and to big webpages

Tags: windows, user-interface, scaling, dpi

In my Microsoft Edge, and Firefox program UI are too big, and also contents of webpages are too big. I have set 100% dpi, no custom scaling. This issue appear only in Firefox and Edge. How can I fix it?

Normal edge on some RDP:

[image: Normal Edge with 100% dpi]

Too big UI on my machine:

[image: Too big UI on my machine]

Comment: Did you log out and log back in yet? DPI changes are not totally effective immediately.

Comment: I have this issue from long months. I made lot of log off, log in, reboots etc.